# what will be the result when more than one user simultaneously access the ghostscript pdf to image converter

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I 'm using ghostscript pdf to image conversion 
'using Cyotek.GhostScript.PdfConversion;'
'using Cyotek.GhostScript;'
 in my webproject it works well when processing single request at a time, but when it process more than one request simultaneously it produce error like 'Failed to process GhostScript command.' my project is a web project here more than one process the website how can i solve this problem i'm helpless please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using Ghostscript via command line (Process.Start), unless native Ghostscript library has been compiled with the **GS_THREADSAFE** define, only one instance at a time (per process) is supported. This means you can process only 1 pdf at a time. I believe **Cyotek.GhostScript** uses Ghostscript API and your native Ghostscript library is compiled without the GS_THREADSAFE.

Eventually you could try to use [**Ghostscript.NET**](http://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) which has ability to load native Ghostscript library from the memory. That way you can have multiple instances of the native Ghostscript library running at a same time each one in it's own context within a same process. (without a need for GS_THREADSAFE).

Comment: Thank you habjan i already tried with  ghostscript.net but it don't know the correct way to process ghostscript.net to convert pdf to images please tell me how to ghostscript.net to convert pdf to images

Comment: Here is one way how to convert PDF to image: https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/RasterizerSample.cs and here is another way: https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/ProcessorSample.cs

Comment: Thank you habjan i tried the above first solution i get the error in the following line "_lastInstalledVersion = GhostscriptVersionInfo.GetLastInstalledVersion();"  the exception was "Ghostscript library not lnstalled exception " i was installed ghostscript library from the following site http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Comment: error Description :                                                                                This managed library is running under 32-bit process and requires 32-bit Ghostscript native library installation on this machine! To download proper Ghostscript native library please visit: http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html   but the library did't get install in my computer that tell installer integrity check has failed  what will be the solution next tell me.

Comment: Hi, anyhow i had installed that library but unlucky this also produce the same error as cyotek.ghostscript produced it did't handle multiple instance

Comment: If you are using GhostscriptRasterizer, change the line rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, _lastInstalledVersion, false); to rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, _lastInstalledVersion, true); 'true' will tell Ghostscript.NET to load native Ghostscript library in it's own context and that will allow you multiple instances per process.

Comment: gr8, I'm glad I could help

Comment: Hi, habjan can i use this solution without installing ghostscript  library(i.e exe file) in my computer?